# Is there an efficient algorithm for generating square matrices up to having same rows and colums

Tags: matrices, algorithms, equivalence-relations

From all square matrices with entries $1,...,n^2$, I am only interested in ones which have different rows or columns.

Since for $n=3$ we already have $9!=362880$ matrices I do not want to sieve through them all and compare the rows and colums for even higher $n$. I wanted to develop an algorithm that would fill blank spaces in the matrix such that it would generate only representatives of different classes.

As an example \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}

both have the rows and colums $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{3,4\},\{2,4\}\}$, so they would be equivalent.

Matrices with same rows and colums can be generated by

- rotating ($4$ results)
- flipping by the main diagonals ($2$ results)
- swapping non-overlapping pairs of rows or pairs of colums

We can maximally swap $\lfloor(n/2)\rfloor$ pairs at one time. We have ${n \choose 2}$ $1$-pair swaps. After picking the first pair, we can pick another pair from the remaining $n-2$ entries, we get ${n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose 2}$ 2-pair swaps. Iterating, we get ${n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose 2}...{n-2(k-1) \choose 2}$ $k$-pair swaps and overall we have the number of swaps

$$S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n/2)\rfloor-1}\prod_{j=0}^k{n-2j \choose 2}$$

A total of $6+2S(n)$ members per class.

---

For $n=2$ it is quite easy to generate the representatives by hand. We have $4!=24$ matrices, so we expect $3$ classes.

We set $1$ into the upper left corner. From the other three numbers we pick two for the antidiagonal, we have ${3 \choose 2}  =3$ possibilities, which are $\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}$, the number which is left lands in the bottom right corner.

Overall we get the representatives

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

For $n=3$ first I thought about reusing the solution for $n=2$, but this did not make it simpler.

Then I thought about picking the main diagonal first, then the second diagonal, and then the third, like this:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3 \\
2 & 1 &2 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Where the numbers are the pick order.

But in $3 \times 3$ matrices this fails as we can also swap the middle row/colum with outer ones and I do not see how to adress this.

I expect each class to have $12$ elements. However then I would get $9!/12=30240$ classes, and I expect the algorithm to be a little complicated. But then I cannot verify reliably that my algorithm is correct due to sheer number of classes.

Comment: I *think* the data you are describing is equivalent to picking two n partitions of the set with n^2 elements into blocks of size n, subject to the requirement that the two partitions are transversal (i.e. pairwise intersections between blocks of the different partitions are size 1). So, to generate / count / uniformly sample these you can enumerate such n partitions, and then for each such n partition enumerate the transversal partitions. Some overcounting will occur because you don't seem to want to distinguish between rows and columns, but I think just by a factor of 2.